# Iterating over 2 lists to find identical elements in the same index

Tags: python

Given two lists with the same length:

```
## TEST 1
lst1 = ["g", "r", "y", "r"]
lst2 = ["y", "g", "o", "r"]
## TEST 2
lst1 = ["g", "r", "y", "r"]
lst2 = ["o", "g", "g", "g"]
```

With an expected output of:

```
## TEST 1 OUTPUT
BWW
## TEST 2 OUTPUT
W
```

Where each identical element that is present in the same index in both lists is given the value of "B" and where each element is present in the other list but not at the same index is given the value "W". If elements don't match nothing is done, see ##TEST2. Output should always print out B before W, unless there is only elements that are present in both lists but not at the same index, as such output would simply be "W".

As of now it simply returns the message

```
ListError list index out or range
```

Comment: share full code then we can help efficently.

Comment: Hey I was under the assumption to only share code that pertained to my issue, I've edited my post for clarity, please tell me if there's anything else I need to add.

Comment: why the expected output is `BWW` and not `WW blank for (y, o) B` (WW B)

Comment: you should debug the code, or add a lot of print/logs, probably you will find out where is the problem

Comment: Essentially elements that match and are in the same index in both lists should be assigned to "B" and elements that are present in both but not in the same index should be assigned to "W". In this task B always comes before W, e.g. output can never be WB or WWB.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I'd do is check that the length of the arrays is the same. This will avoid you conflicts, since you're iterating over both arrays using the length of one of them.

Second thing, do not remove elements from an array you're iterating over.
In this part:

```
    else:
    if guess[i] in hidden:
        hidden_copy.remove(guess[i])
        hidden.remove(guess[i])
        feedback += ["W"]
```

you remove items from `hidden` which you might need for the next index.

Since you're already copying your `hidden` array, I'd recommend to remove the items only from the copy `hidden_copy` and leave the original as is, so you can continue iterating over it (like in `if guess[i] == hidden[i]:`) without issues.

This should work:

```
def give_feedback(hidden, guess):
    hidden_copy = hidden[:]
    feedback = []

    for i in range(len(guess)):
        if guess[i] == hidden[i]:
            hidden_copy.remove(guess[i])
            feedback += ["B"]
        else:
            if guess[i] in hidden:
                hidden_copy.remove(guess[i])
                feedback += ["W"]
return sorted(feedback)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way using **ZIP()** to iterate multiple data structure at a time by same index.

```
lst1 = ["g", "r", "y", "r"]
lst2 = ["y", "g", "o", "r"]
hidden_copy = lst1[:]
feedback = []
for i,j in zip(lst1,lst2):
    if j == i:
        hidden_copy.remove(i)
        feedback += ["B"]
    else:
        if i in lst1:
            hidden_copy.remove(i)
            feedback += ["W"]
sorted(feedback)
```

Answer (score 0):

In general for these kinds of problems, there are multiple solutions. It depends on what you want to optimize. Commonly one wants to optimize time complexity i.e. how the run time scales with the length of your input. With the currently presented solutions, a lot of time is spent on checking if elements are present in arrays, which scaled quite poorly if your input array is long.

A more efficient solution could be to use a counter:

```
from collections import Counter

def give_feedback(hidden, guess):

    hidden_c = Counter(hidden)
    guess_c = Counter(guess)

    elements_in_both_lists = 0
    for x in hidden_c:
        elements_in_both_lists += min(hidden_c[x], guess_c[x])

    elements_at_same_index = 0
    for i, j in zip(hidden, guess):
        if i == j:
            elements_at_same_index += 1

    result = "B" * elements_at_same_index + "W" * (elements_in_both_lists - elements_at_same_index)

    return result
```